# Is it possible to connect Node.js and RED5?

Tags: node.js, chat, red5

I have the following problem.

I have a chat developed with ActionScript3 (AS3), SharedObjects (SO) and RED5. Well, this works correctly. Now, I'm developing a chat using Node.js, and this works correctly too.

My question/problem is how can I connect these 2 chats. Is it possible to send messages between Node.js and RED5? I want that one user that is chatting using Node.js chat and another user that is chatting using RED5 chat, can chat together.

Someone knows some solution? It's possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to code some server side servlet in Java to proxy your Node.js messages to and from the red5 chat.
Are you familiar with the Red5 API and have some understanding of the Java Servlet Container ? Cause you will need that to implement a solution.
Red5 is a server side technology that runs in the Tomcat Servlet Container. Propably Node.js could send a message to red5 via a simple servlet, that will then forward the message to all connected clients.
The other way round you could catch all chat messages on Red5 server side and then forward the messages to Node.js (however I don't know what incoming message receiver's you can code in Node.js).

Sebastian

Comment: Thank you Sebastian, I'm not familiar with RED5 APi neither Java Servlet, but I'm going to learn about that.